# Android Studio Beta 1.2 issue formatting xml-layout

Tags: android, android-studio, formatting, xml-layout

Recently I’ve upgraded from Android Studio 1 to Android Studio Beta 1.2.

And among other issues, it seems that the shortcut *(Option + Command + L)* for formatting the xml-layouts it doesn’t reorganice code any more.

In the previous version of Android Studio, if you had something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10dp"
    android:id="@+id/rl_avatar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

After formatting you got the next result:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_avatar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10dp">
```

But now I just get this message: “No lines changed. Code is already properly formatted”

Is there any kind of configuration that I’m missing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L, you should have a dialog where you can tick "Rearrange".